# Draw a 10% filled rectangle

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to draw a 10% filled rectangle with opencv, so i had the idea to first choose two points over an image that will contain the first triangle using a mouse callback, then draw a filled one using the two points here is the code i used

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

class ObstacleDrawer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pp =[]

    def callback(self,event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == 1: self.pp.append((x,y))

    def run(self):
        cv2.namedWindow('img')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('img', self.callback)

        while True:
            for image in glob.glob('/home/aub/myflower/flower_photos/dandelion/*.jpg'):
                img = cv2.imread(image)
                xs = [p[0] for p in self.pp]
                ys = [p[1] for p in self.pp]
                cv2.rectangle(img, (xs[0], (ys[0]-ys[1])/2), (xs[1], (ys[0]-ys[1])/2 + (ys[0]-ys[1])/10), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.imshow('img', img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = ObstacleDrawer()
    image = z.run()
```

But unfortunately it doesn't, it doesn't even show the image, any suggestions please

Comment: Based on what you added the run function is not called anywhere. Also it is wrong to put a new line between the declaration of the function and its body.

Comment: thank you so much, i will try your advices

Comment: i did some modification, that u can check above and now it gives me this error cv2.rectangle(img, (xs[0], (ys[0]-ys[1])/2), (xs[1], (ys[0]-ys[1])/2 + (ys[0]-ys[1])/10), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you try to do any debugging? Just add some print statements before the line that gives the error, to show the values of the the variables being indexed, e.g. `xs`, `ys`

Comment: thank you I did some debugging, and it works now